# pre-populating DOB fields in Magento registration form

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to pre-populate some fields in Magento's customer registration form. I was able to get the formData from the register block and do things like `->setFirstname()` which works great, but I am having trouble doing the same with the DOB widget.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Eyal

Comment: Add name of block class and code you've already written to populate first name and dob. Otherwise it's not clear - where you work and what Magento blocks and routines you use.

Comment: Sorry @Andrey, you are right about this.
I was referring the the Dob Widget withing Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register as seen from a class that extends Mage_Customer_AccountController.
I will try to be more accurate next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got pointed at the right direction by alan storm,
answer was to call ->setDob('1999-1-15')
on the formData member of the block.

This is all within a class that extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
and the outline of the code is:

```
$year='1999';
$month='1';
$day='15';
$layout=$this->getLayout();

/*
The register block is a type="customer/form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml" 
i.e. Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register
*/

$registerBlock=$layout->getBlock('customer_form_register'); 
$register_form_data=$registerBlock->getFormData();
$register_form_data->setDob($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);
```